# Sorting algorithm times using sorting methods

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, computation-theory

So I just learned about sorting algorithm s bubble, merge, insertion, sort etc. they all seem to be very similar in their methods of sorting with what seems to me minimal changes in their approach. So why do they produce such different sorting times ie O(n^2) vs O(nlogn) as an example

Comment: So your question is why the complexity of different algorithms are not the same? *Because they're different algorithms*.

Comment: Essentially. I understand that through the different methods the level of complexity in the searching reduced by factors dependent upon the method but it's my lack of understanding on how time complexity works that I don't inderstand why this produces should a different sorting time

Comment: I would be inclined to disagree with you on your statement that "their methods of sorting with what seems to me minimal changes in their approach". Sorting function vary in complexity because they aren't similar. For example recursive and not recursive sorting functions. Insertion sort: repeatedly add new element to the sorted result.
Bubble sort: repeatedly compare neighbor pairs and swap if necessary. I feel like this is a bad question because the question showed no research effort.

Comment: Nitpick: recursive vs iterative is about implementation, and they can both be coaxed into looking like the other. Merge sort isn't "recursive," it's divide and conquer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "similarity" (?!) that you see is completely illusory.

The elementary, O(N squared), approaches, repeat their workings over and over, without taking any advantage, for the "next step", of any work done on the "previous step".  So the first step takes time proportional to N, the second one to N-1, and so on -- and the resulting sum of integers from 1 to N is proportional to N squared.

For example, in selection sort, you are looking each time for the smallest element in the I:N section, where I is at first 0, then 1, etc.  This is (and must be) done by inspecting all those elements, because no care was previously taken to afford any lesser amount of work on subsequent passes by taking any advantage of previous ones.  Once you've found that smallest element, you swap it with the I-th element, increment I, and continue.  O(N squared) of course.

The advanced, O(N log N), approaches, are cleverly structured to take advantage in following steps of work done in previous steps.  That difference, compared to the elementary approaches, is so pervasive and deep, that, if one cannot perceive it, that speaks chiefly about the acuity of one's perception, not about the approaches themselves:-).

For example, in merge sort, you logically split the array into two sections, 0 to half-length and half-length to length.  Once each half is sorted (recursively by the same means, until the length gets short enough), the two halves are merged, which itself is a linear sub-step.

Since you're halving every time, you clearly need a number of steps proportional to log N, and, as each step is O(N), obviously you get the very desirable O(N log N) as a result.

Python's "timsort" is a "natural mergesort", i.e, a variant of mergesort tuned to take advantage of already-sorted (or reverse-sorted) parts of the array, which it recognizes rapidly and avoids spending any further work on.  This doesn't change big-O because that's about **worst**-case time -- but **expected** time crashes much further down because in so many real-life cases some partial sortedness **is** present.

(Note that, going by the rigid definition of big-O, quicksort isn't quick at all -- it's worst-case proportional to N squared, when you just happen to pick a terrible pivot each and every time... **expected-time** wise it's fine, though nowhere as good as timsort, because in real life the situations where you repeatedly pick a disaster pivot are exceedingly rare... but, **worst**-case, they **might** happen!-).

`timsort` is **so** good as to blow away even very experienced programmers.  I don't count because I'm a friend of the inventor, Tim Peters, and a Python fanatic, so my bias is obvious.  But, consider...

...I remember a "tech talk" at Google where timsort was being presented.  Sitting next to me in the front row was Josh Bloch, then also a Googler, and Java expert extraordinaire.  Less than mid-way through the talk he couldn't resist any more - he opened his laptop and started hacking to see if it could possibly be as good as the excellent, sharp technical presentation seemed to show it would be.

As a result, `timsort` is now also the sorting algorithm in recent releases of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), though only for user-defined objects (arrays of primitives are still sorted the old way, quickersort [*] I believe -- I don't know which Java peculiarities determined this "split" design choice, my Java-fu being rather weak:-).

[*] that's essentially quicksort plus some hacks for pivot choice to try and avoid the poison cases -- and it's also what Python used to use before Tim Peters gave this one immortal contribution out of the many important ones he's made over the decades.

The results are sometimes surprising to people with CS background (like Tim, I have the luck of having a far-ago academic background, not in CS, but in EE, which helps a lot:-).  Say, for example, that you must maintain an ever-growing array that is always sorted at any point in time, as new incoming data points must get added to the array.

The classic approach would use bisection, O(log N), to find the proper insertion point for each new incoming data point -- but then, to put the new data in the right place, you need to shift what comes after it by one slot, that's O(N).

With timsort, you just append the new data point to the array, then sort the array -- that's O(N) for timsort in this case (as it's so awesome in exploiting the already-sorted nature of the first N-1 items!-).

You can think of timsort as pushing the "take advantage of work previously done" to a new extreme -- where not only work previously done by the algorithm itself, but also other influences by other aspects of real-life data processing (causing segments to be sorted in advance), are all exploited to the hilt.

Then we could move into bucket sort and radix sort, which change the plane of discourse -- which in traditional sorting limits one to being able to compare two items -- by exploiting the items' internal structure.

Or a similar example -- presented by Bentley in his immortal book "Programming Pearls" -- of needing to sort an array of several million unique positive integers, each constrained to be 24 bits long.

He solved it with an auxiliary array of 16M bits -- just 2M bytes after all -- initially all zeroes: one pass through the input array to set the corresponding bits in the auxiliary array, then one pass through the auxiliary array to form the required integers again where `1`s are found -- and bang, O(N) [and very speedy:-)] sorting for this special but important case!-)

Comment: *if you cannot perceive it, that speaks about the acuity of your perception* - thats deep...

Comment: Good answer sorting concepts were explained well so accepting but feel as if the negativity was unwarranted. Beginning comp sci major just learning about these kinds of things haven't had much experience with how time complexity works yet.

Comment: @Overflow2341313, never having taken even one CS class (unless you count a single "Fortran programming" course that was mostly rehashing a subset of the reference manual:-) I have a hard time connecting with CS people -- I'm entirely self-taught in the field, "standing on the shoulders of giants" who have written incredibly good books, and open-source software packages, one can study at one's own pace.  In the time one CS class would take I can absorb 5-10 such books and packages and learn SO much more.  (Ditto for management & entrepreneurship, BTW, also fields where I'm self-taught:-).